# Thumbnail and Video from cloudflare are mirror of earch other

Tags: ios, swift, camera, cloudflare, swiftycam

I am uploading video from front cam with the help of [SwiftyCam](https://github.com/Awalz/SwiftyCam) to [cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/) ... it returns me a .m3u8 video link with a thumbnail...

but both are opposite in direction (mirror of each other)...

- It's happening only from the front cam ...
- I am uploading only video, not any other thing ...
- native front camera like `UIImagePickerController` flip the video right after recording ... [SwiftyCam](https://github.com/Awalz/SwiftyCam) prevent this but it cost me the thumbnail flip when getting things back from [cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/) ...
- I can't flip the thumbnail locally to make it match with the video ... this gonna mess up on Android devices and video recorded from the back camera ...

I am unable to find any effective solution so far ...